# Solana - How to determine Finality

Tags: solana

I'm currently working on a backend system that needs to determine if a transaction on Solana is final. I know that there is a `commitment: "max"` field in the RPC methods. Is this the same as it being final - meaning reorgs are not possible anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, and the commitment parameter has even been renamed from `"max"` to `"finalized"` to make that clearer: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#configuring-state-commitment

Comment: Thanks, Is max and finalized the same?